# Is the direct sum of a quotient space with its quotient isomorphic to the original space?

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $A\subset B$ be left $R$-submodules of $M$. Is it the case that 
$$\phi: A/B \oplus B \to A,\;\;\; \phi((a+B) + b) = a +b$$
is an isomorphism?

I've made a proof, but I'm not entirely convinced. In particular consider the following short exact sequence,
$$0 \to G \to G'\to G'' \to 0.$$
From the first isomorphism theorem, $G \cong \text{im}\ f$ and $G'/\text{im}\ f \cong G''$, so if my claim were true it would seem that $G' \cong G'' \oplus \text{im}\ f \cong G'' \oplus G$! Since there exist non-split exact sequences, my claim musn't hold always..

Comment: First of all, is $\phi$ well-defined? What if $a+B=a'+B$? Also, you might be interested in the group $\text{Ext}^1(A/B,B)$ which is not always trivial!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just not true. 
Consider e.g. $R=\Bbb Z$ with $A=\Bbb Z_4$, $\, B=\Bbb Z_2$. Then $A/B=\Bbb Z_2$ but $\Bbb Z_2\times \Bbb Z_2\not\cong \Bbb Z_4$.

Comment: Are there general conditions whereby this holds? It seems like all of the modules given in your example have torsion...

Comment: Well, if $R$ is e.g. a field, or a *semisimple* ring (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semisimple_module#Semisimple_rings), or just $A$ is a semisimple module, then this holds, i.e. every submodule of $A$ is a direct summand.

Comment: You can also make an example with $A,B$ torsionfree, e.g. $0\to\Bbb Z\overset{\cdot2}\to\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z_2\to 0$.